# Determining selected value in cfselect and setting it to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have a couple of dropdown menus using cfselect e.g. city and country. I'm wondering how I determine the selected value and set variables to those values for use in another cfform.

Thanks.

Comment: @Yatrix - Apologies. Went back and accepted the questions I could remember. Will do better in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form1.cfm

```
<cfselect name="city">
<cfselect name="country">
```

After submitting the form to form2.cfm, city and country are available in the form scope and contain the selected choices by the user. No different than an HTML form?

Form2.cfm

```
<cfinput name="chosenCity" value="#form.city#">
<cfinput name="chosenCountry" value="#form.country#">
```

Comment: So I do need to submit the form in order to get the values. Can I do this on onChange? If so, do I need to use javascript? I don't have a submit button for these cfforms. I do on another cfform on the same page. I'm trying to place the selected values to this form and then send. Thanks.

Comment: @Jason: Sounds like you just need a little JavaScript. You would do well to add some code to your question and get _specific_ about the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Well if you do an submit onChange and you have more than one select box, it will prematurely submit the form.  The form needs to be submitted via a FORM POST method for these variables to show up in the FORM scope.